# Aurelia JS Dependencies

Tags: javascript, aurelia

First, I do not have much background in JS; Aurelia JS is not working for me, I get the following error in Chrome:

1) TypeError: e.configure is not a function
    at aurelia-core.min.js:1

If I use the Aurelia basic-aurelia-project.zip

2) I get Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot set SystemJS.map["aurelia-framework"] directly. Use SystemJS.config({ map: { "aurelia-framework": ... } }) rather.

If I maken eclipse project and use the below in index.html

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js"></script>
<script src="lib/aurelia-core.min.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
</script>
```

If I have to follow simple dependency inclusion model with 'script' elements in head/body what are the scripts to be included.

In addition, I did not find any CDN link for Aurelia, which makes me wonder if Aurelia is production ready or a mere Beta level upcoming JS framework.

I do not use Node.js etc. so npm etc. does not work for me. Is there a simpler way of using Aurelia (in AngularJS 1.x style including script elements) or there is some other more complicated way.

I am not sure if Aurelia is worth the effort to adopt in terms of configuration/dependency (my opinion only).

If someone can help me resolve the above problems & dependencies it shall be great.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have brought in any configuration for System.JS.  Given your lack of Modern JavaScript experience, I would recommend learning Aurelia using our CLI instead of trying to build a custom setup like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer this question based on **my opinon**.

> In addition, I did not find any CDN link for Aurelia, which makes me
>   wonder if Aurelia is production ready or a mere Beta level upcoming JS
>   framework.

You may not find any CDN link for Aurelia because it's not like other libraries, such as jQuery. There's no reason for a CDN link because you would never load it using script tags in a production environment (unless if you really know what you're doing). Aurelia (as any other modern js framework) was made to be used with modern loading and bundling tools.

> I do not use Node.js etc. so npm etc. does not work for me. Is there a
>   simpler way of using Aurelia (in AngularJS 1.x style including script
>   elements) or there is some other more complicated way.

I'm sorry to tell you this, but if you want to use a modern JS framework (Aurelia, Angular2, Vue.js), you will have to deal with node.js, npm, etc. All modern js frameworks have some building process that run under a node.js environment. It's possible to avoid it, but this would only make things harder.

There are simpler ways to use Aurelia, like the project you've mentioned in your question. However, It was mainly made for learning purposes. You can still use them in a real scenario but you will find a lot of difficulties since there will be no tool to help you.

NodeJS tools are there to help us! Give them a chance and you won't regret it. Trust me :)

If you have some strict companies rules that don't allow you to use Node, I think you should to talk to your leaders and try to workaround that.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it does moke things clear for me, one point of note, I actually could use Vue.js with simple script tag inclusion. I understand NodeJS & its associated tools are very powerful, however, I have a real challenge towards getting NodeJS and other advanced JS skills, however, your answer was quite helpful

Answer (score 0):

@Fabio Luz,
please excuse me, this is not an answer, but a longer note to your answer - there might be a scenario for Aurelia modules in CDN...

I understand, that it is very good to have ability to bundle and do the tree shaking of the framework library for the "lonely" SPA architecture. But I am not sure and I wonder whether it would be better to have some different approach - e.g. having the certain Aurelia modules  in a CDN. I wonder that in case of a possible decision e.g. to use Aurelia commonly as a platform for continuous development of customization for SharePoint Online /Office365 using the SharePoint Framework. I have tried to configure Aurelia as externals for the webpack in a spfx solution, but I was unsuccessful. I am also not so familiar with all the tooling, so I might have done some beginner's mistake :(. Pity, that the Aurelia cli and the spfx tooling versions are not in a harmony currently - the spfx has to use the gulp with webpack ver.3, though the aurelia works with newer webpack ver.4